# Generating pre defined HTML links when a set of check boxes are checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm creating a HTML document where i have close to 50 check boxes. My objective is to generate  pre defined links which are to be generated when a check box is checked. The links should be opened in separate tabs of the browser when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: You will have more than one boxes checked while clicking submit..? Also no jQuery usage?

Comment: yes thats correct. There will be more than one check box checked. Not much keen on using jquery, instead java script is more welcome.

Comment: I think you'll find that you can't easily open multiple tabs in response to a single click. Most browsers will prevent this type of behavior because abuse from unscrupulous advertisers. I am not positive that you can't find a solution that may work in certain circumstances/browsers, but I doubt you will be successful.

Comment: would it  be possible to just generate the links in a text area at  least. This can be used instead of opening the same in multiple tab right?

Comment: Refer [Link](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/05/15/how-to-loop-through-checkboxes-or-radio-button-groups-via-javascript/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I shall refer the link and make the maximum use of it..

Answer (score 0):

```
var preDefinedLinkValues = ["www.google.com", "www.gmail.com",.....];
function openLinks(form) {
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');//this will open the link in new tab.
for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++ ) {
if (form.elements[i].checked == true) {
link.setAttribute('href', preDefinedLinkValues[i]);
link.click();
}
}
}
```